# Fiddling with MySQL: information_scheme

Tags: mysql

Good Day!

So I've been fiddling with MySQL and encountered an obstacle. Here's the code:

```
SELECT table_name, table_rows, data_length, update_time FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_name IN
('table_1' , 'table_2' , 'table_3' , 'table_4')
```

What I'm trying to do is to check table status via information_scheme. And it works fine - until any given table in the above code does not exist. 
The goal is to get a result which should look like this:

```
+------------------+------------+-------------+---------------------+
| table_name       | table_rows | data_length | update_time         |
+------------------+------------+-------------+---------------------+
| table_1          |    7041979 |  5497161940 | 2016-04-07 02:53:41 |
| table_3          |       NULL |       NULL  |                NULL |
```

and I can't find a way to do it. Read a ton of info about it and still can't wrap my head around it. Have a feeling this should be solved simple and elegant, but how?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use `left join` instead:

```
SELECT tn.table_name, t.table_rows, t.data_length, t.update_time
FROM (SELECT 'table_1' as table_name UNION ALL
      SELECT 'table_2' as table_name UNION ALL
      SELECT 'table_3' as table_name UNION ALL
      SELECT 'table_4' as table_name
     ) tn LEFT JOIN
     information_schema.tables t
     ON tn.table_name = t.table_name;
```

Comment: Is it possible **without** monstrous construction like 

'select 'table_1' as ... select 'table_2'  ?

My be stored proc?

Anyway, good solution, but I want use tables list like ('a', 'b', 'c', 'foo', 'bar', 'etc').
Thanx

Comment: @Arris . . . Perhaps you already have the relevant names stored in another table and can use that as the source.

Comment: no. Based on your response, I wrote function: 

https://gist.github.com/KarelWintersky/90f1a2a0d3340cf4ba3b5e106afac589